# How to update changes to a list made in a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

Basically, what I want to do is to update the changes made inside a recursive call to my main list. I tried the below, but it is creating a new list every time  and forgetting the mother list, instead returning a new child list. Lemmi explain with a basic code:

```
def woah(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        arr[-1], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[-1]
        print(arr) //to keep track of changes
        return woah(arr[:-1])

woah([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

>> [6, 3, 4, 5, 2]
   [5, 3, 4, 6]
   [4, 3, 5]
   [3, 4]
```

I want it to finally return :

> > output : [3, 4, 5, 6, 2]

Inside changes I think should've taken place to reach the desired output:

> > [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] --> [6, 3, 4, 5, 2] --> [5, 3, 4, 6, 2] --> [4, 3, 5, 6, 2] --> [3, 4, 5, 6, 2]

I just want to return the changes to the main mother list without creating any new lists. How do I do that?

Comment: Where did that 5 come from?

Comment: @ipaleka I missed that. Thanks, I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `return woah(arr[:-1])`, you leave out the last element and thats not what you want. Try something like this

```
def woah(arr, n=1): 
    if len(arr) > n:
        arr[-n], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[-n]
        print(arr)
        return woah(arr, n+1)
    else:
        return arr

woah([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

**Output**

```
[6, 3, 4, 5, 2]
[5, 3, 4, 6, 2]
[4, 3, 5, 6, 2]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A little change:

```py
def woah(arr, l):
    if l > 1:
        arr[l-1], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[l-1]
        print(arr) # to keep track of changes
        return woah(arr, l-1)

    return arr

arr = [2, 3 ,4, 5 , 6]
woah(arr, len(arr)) # arr will be changed, and you can also accept the return value
```

A better way is define one inner function, so you can just pass arr. Leave it with you :-)

Answer (score 1):

since you pass a shorter list each time, the list gets shorter and shorter.
This shoud work:

```
def woah(arr, fixed):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        arr[-1], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[-1]
        print(arr+fixed) #to keep track of changes
        return woah(arr[:-1],[arr[-1]]+fixed)

woah([2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [])
```